# Raise a .NET "OK" Event in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

In the documentation of the Siemens TIA-Portal Openness API you can read the following:

[image: Screenshot Siemens API]

There is an event, when a confirmation box opens, and an event when the confirmation is given by the user.

```
//Register event handler for Notification-Event
....
tiaPortal.Notification += TiaPortal_Notification;
....
private static void TiaPortal_Notification(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
{
....
}
//Register event handler for Confirmation-Event
....
tiaPortal.Confirmation += TiaPortal_Confirmation;
....
private static void TiaPortal_Confirmation(object sender, ConfirmationEventArgs e)
{
....
}
```

The documentation gives this much information on reacting to the events

[image]

I want to react on the notification event. But the NotificationEventArgs Class does not contain an result attribute which i can write on, and does not contain any method of some kind to send a confirmation. There is only one writeable attribute, called IsHandled. But nothing happens if i write to that, so i suggest this is only an internal confirmation

[image]

My understanding of the api documentation ist, that it is something native of c#/.net? maybe a function of some kind, to raise reactions on events?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do - surely you want to *react* to events rather than *raising* them yourself? Please clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: "documentation gives me only this much information" followed by German text that most readers here can't understand is pretty much the same as if you hadn't posted that image at all

Comment: These confirmations ("Bestätigungen") are an internal feature of that "TIA-Openess" API or platform by Siemens. Seems you have to provide one of the codes ("Choices") listes and assign it to ConformationEventArgs.Result to tell that API how/whether to process after the event was raised.
It's sth specific to that API, not a feature of .NET.

Comment: I think you meant it has no writeable attributes.

Comment: English version of the PDF: https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/attachments/109773802/TIAPortalOpenness_en-US.pdf?download=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is valid for TIA 16 with Openness API V16.

**Confirmations:** If a prompt is triggered in TIA Portal that requires a user decision (i.e. has more than one button), ConfirmationEvent is raised, and it definitely happens prior to any decision being made by the user.

Set IsHandled, then set the Result value. That's all you need to do.

```
private static void Tiap_Confirmation(object sender, ConfirmationEventArgs e)
{
    //signal to TIA Portal that the event is handled
    e.IsHandled = true;

    //handle the various events
    if (CONDITIONS_FOR_CHOOSING_YES)
        e.Result = ConfirmationResult.Yes;

    if (CONDITIONS_FOR_CHOOSING_CANCEL)
        e.Result = ConfirmationResult.Cancel;

    ...

}
```

**Notifications:** NotificationEvent is only raised for prompts that have *one* button.  The example below is for a .NET Framework console application.

```
using Siemens.Engineering;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace OpennessConsoleTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //attach to the first tia portal process found
            TiaPortal tiap = TiaPortal.GetProcesses().First().Attach();

            //subscribe to confirmation event
            tiap.Notification += Tiap_Notification;

            //pause
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for events.  Press Ctrl+C to quit");

            //sleep indefinitely.  User must ctrl+C out of this
            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        private static void Tiap_Notification(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            e.IsHandled = true;

            Console.WriteLine("*****Notification*****");
            Console.WriteLine("Caption: " + e.Caption);
            Console.WriteLine("Text: " + e.Text);
            Console.WriteLine("DetailText: " + e.DetailText);
        }

    }
}
```

*An important note*: According to my testing, some prompts do not raise an event even if subscribed, for example "Subfolder already exists" when extracting an archive.  This puts TIA Portal into a locked state until you stop your application.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Do you also know what happens if i had a prompt with only one button, how would i commit that one? Is the IsHandled property enough? Nothing seems to happen if i only set the is handled property to true.

Comment: Not sure.  I've not been able to trigger a single-button prompt for testing on demand - how do you do it?  Let me know and I'll check it out.

Comment: The prompt occured when opening a project after updating to a new update of tia portal (TIA V16 Update 1 to TIA V1 Update 3 for example). I will try to reproduce an easier way.

Comment: I created a simple console app (above) and tested it successfully by opening a TIA16 Update 1 project in TIA 16 Update 4 (same as your example).  The prompt details were output to the console and TIA continued to run.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help! I actually got it to work, but i do not know what i did different this time...

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a (not optimal) translation into German. What they mean is you need to set a field in the event args you got. This is a normal pattern in .NET.

Something like this (don't have the library for syntax check but you should get what I mean):

```
private static void TiaPortal_Confirmation(object sender, ConfirmationEventArgs e)
{
    // do your thing, open a confirmation dialog or something, then:
    e.Result = Choices.OK;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer. My problem is, that the ConfirmationEventArgs only contains readable attributes. no attribute is writeable

Comment: @Felix Without the documentation of that specific API it is hard to tell. IMHO `e.Result`, if present in the `ConfirmationEventArgs`, should be writeable.

Comment: Did you actually try the code snippet in this answer, or did you just conclude from IntelliSense? Also, if you actually can't modify Result by assigning to it - have you tried dotting into Result to see if there are some methods that will allow feedback? Many APIs of this kind are poorly made, and the docs are often off, so do experiment and research aggressively to figure this out.

Comment: Yes i tried it, there is no Result attribute and all other attributes are not writeable. I tried to search for methods that allow me to give feedback, but could not find any, not in the documentation and not in the code

Comment: I'm looking at the PDF Jon Skeet pointed to, and I suspect you can set Result in the Notification event. Have you tried that, or just the Confirmation event so far? (edit: Oh, I just saw something else to the contrary, so I'm probably wrong, but please try anyway.)

Comment: Is the DLL available somewhere, so we can perhaps help that way?

Comment: I can set the Result parameter in the Confirmation Event, but this event only fires when the confirmation has already taken place (confirmed by user). So i suspect i would need to set it in the Notification Event, but as i said, there is no result attribute or something compareable

Comment: The .dll ist available in siemens products, but i do not know if i am allowed to share that...